# my expresion for using the like 'XXX%' to express startswith isn't accepted by .query() of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, startswith

This is the expression that I want to pass to the function .query() of pandas
 `external_identifier LIKE '16%'and act_rea in ['None']`
But it brings this error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the issue in fact I can't use statswith with the expression of like and % 
The right expression is :

```
pandas.query('external_identifier.str.startswith("16") and act_rea in ["None"] ')
```

Comment: This should be part of your question @asmatrk?